How to install pytorch in WSL2
I installed Minconda on WSL and created a virtual environment called tf-wsl.
I only ran one command when installing the tensorflow library.
I was able to detect my gpu when testing tensorflow. Do I have to download cuda to connect to tensorflow? Running nvcc -v terminal only requires me to download nvidia-cuda-toolkit.
Do I need to download nvidia-cuda-toolkit? Do I need to download it if I want to install pytorch?
I have searched a lot on the internet but I still don't understand what I need to do. I hope someone can give me some pointers.
